# Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 white text on white BG in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: gnome, 15.04, desktop-background, text

I have Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 installed right now on my PC.

I have this issue where in Ubuntu Software Center when I select an item it then appears as white text on white background.
It isn't that it would have an impact on my overall experience, it is only a thing of visual matter; but for me, visual look and feel is very important since I use this distribution of Ubuntu as my 'daily driver'.

I had Ubuntu (Desktop) 15.04 before and it hadn't such a problem as described here with Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.

Is there a way to fix it (if it is an issue/bug) or to change those colors somehow?
For more specific description and understanding of my problem see the screenshot that I attached.

Thank you in advance for all your answers!

(P.S.: I love Gnome so I do not want to go back to Unity. Cheers.)

[image: Screenshot of the problem - see the LibreOffice icon and description of it - this is the thing that I'm trying to describe.]

Comment: No one? Please, this problem really annoyes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out an answer myself. 
A solution is to install 3rd party themes like Numix, Paper, etc...

It fixed almost entirely this issue.